# How to change ng-view when button clicked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook

I want to change my view when the FB Auth is  true, and im trying this

```
app.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope','$location',function($scope) {
$scope.name="Inice de Sesion por favor";
$scope.FBLogin=function(){
FB.login( function(response){
   if(response.authResponse){
      //$scope.view="#!/view2"
      $location.path("#!/view2");
      $scope.name="Sesion iniciada";
      console.log("Bienvenido! Cargando tu informacion...");
      FB.api('/me',function(response){
        console.log("Es bueno verte de nuevo, " + response.name +   
'.');
        console.log(response);
        var tokenAcceso=FB.getAuthResponse();
        console.log(tokenAcceso);
      });
    }else{
      console.log("Error al autentificar al usuario");
    }
});
};
}]);
```

and inside my html

```
<div class="boton-agregar" ng-controller="View1Ctrl">
<h1>{{name}}</h1>
<ons-button ng-click="FBLogin()">Iniciar sesion con FaceBook</ons-
button>
</div>
</ons-page>
```

so the question is, how to change the view when i click in the button and my function in the fb auth part the response is true?

Answer (score 0):

After your

```
var tokenAcceso=FB.getAuthResponse();
```

do

```
$location.path('/yourview');
```

Comment: That didnt work, when i click and login into facebook, the page stays on the same view

Comment: Can you share your routing?

Answer (score 0):

```
.controller('LoginController', ['$location, function ($location) {
    $scope.FBLogin=function(){
FB.login( function(response){
   if(response.authResponse){
      //$scope.view="#!/view2"
      $location.path("#!/view2");
      $scope.name="Sesion iniciada";
      console.log("Bienvenido! Cargando tu informacion...");
      FB.api('/me',function(response){
        console.log("Es bueno verte de nuevo, " + response.name +   
'.');
        console.log(response);
        var tokenAcceso=FB.getAuthResponse();
        console.log(tokenAcceso);
        $location.path('/yourcomponent'); 
      });
    }else{
      console.log("Error al autentificar al usuario");
    }
});
};
}
```